# shouldperformSegueWithIdentifier does not work properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to understand how "shouldperformSegueWithIdentifier".
in the storyBoard, I created three scenes "scene1, scene2,scene3". Scene1 is linked to scene2 via a segue called "scene1To2", scene2 is linked to scene3 via a segue called "scene2To3" and scene3 is linked to scene1 via a segue called "scene3To1".

As shown in the code below, I called "shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier" and it returned NO if the segue's identifier is "scene3To1".

At run time, I expected when I try to transit from scene3 to scene1 via "scene3To1", the transition will not occur, but it occurred normally…so what is the purpose of "shouldperformSegueWithIdentifier"

**code**:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a      
 nib.
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 - (IBAction)from1To2:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"in 1st scene");

       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"scene1To2" sender:self];
  }

   - (IBAction)from2To3:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"in 2nd scene");

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"scene2To3" sender:self];
    }

   - (IBAction)from3To1:(id)sender {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"scene3To1" sender:self];


   NSLog(@"in 3rd scene");
  }


  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
  {
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue");

     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"scene1To2"])
      {
      NSLog(@"transiting from scene1To2");

     } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"scene2To3"])
     {
     NSLog(@"transiting from scene2To3");

     } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"scene3To1"])

    {
    NSLog(@"transition from scene 3 back to scene 1");
    }

    }

  -(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier  
   sender:(id)sender
   {
   NSLog(@"shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier");

   if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"scene3To1"])
   {
    return NO;
    }


  return YES;
   }

  @end
```

**output**:

```
2017-06-06 16:02:07.301 UnwindSegue-1[699:19450] in 1st scene
2017-06-06 16:02:07.315 UnwindSegue-1[699:19450] prepareForSegue
2017-06-06 16:02:07.316 UnwindSegue-1[699:19450] transiting from  
scene1To2
2017-06-06 16:02:07.320 UnwindSegue-1[699:19450]    
shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier
2017-06-06 16:02:08.245 UnwindSegue-1[699:19450] in 2nd scene

2017-06-06 16:02:08.260 UnwindSegue-1[699:19450] prepareForSegue
2017-06-06 16:02:08.260 UnwindSegue-1[699:19450] transiting from    
scene2To3

2017-06-06 16:02:08.265 UnwindSegue-1[699:19450]    
shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier
2017-06-06 16:02:09.165 UnwindSegue-1[699:19450] prepareForSegue
2017-06-06 16:02:09.165 UnwindSegue-1[699:19450] transition from 
scene 3 back to scene 1
2017-06-06 16:02:09.167 UnwindSegue-1[699:19450] in 3rd scene
2017-06-06 16:02:09.167 UnwindSegue-1[699:19450] 
shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier
```

*StoryBoard**:

[image]

Comment: Is this code duplicated in all three view controllers?

Comment: Is `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` even called? Is `from3To1:` called?

Comment: @Larme please see the output section above, i posted the output i received

Comment: @DonMag no, I have one class, called ViewController and the three view controllers are associated to it

Comment: Hmmm... I can't find documentation on this, but it appears that `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` is only called when the segue is triggered automatically.

Comment: How did you connect your segues? From Button to other VC, or from VC to other VC? I'd suggest to connect VC to VC.

Comment: When I ran your code, I only get `NSLog(@"shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier");` when I added automatic segues... I do **not** get it when using `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: I don't understand the point of calling into cause 'shouldPerformSegue' when you can just put an if-then-else in your implementation.

Comment: @Larme please have a look at the StoryBoard section I posted above, I transit from a scene to another using a button

Comment: How did you create the segue? From connection from the button to the next ViewController? If yes, delete it, and redo it, but starting from selecting the ViewController to the next ViewController

Comment: @lookaji would you clarify further

Comment: @Larme I deleted the connection between the button and the VC, and created the segues directly from each VC to the next VC…and the transition from VC to the next is happening normally..despit shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier returns "NO"

Comment: Do you have no other code? I cannot duplicate the behavior you are seeing. I *only* trigger `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` if it's an automatic segue, not a manual one. Plus... the debug console output looks wrong... Under normal conditions, `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` is called *before* `prepareForSegue` - but your output shows it being called *after*?

Comment: @DonMag so, creating segues from the StoryBoard, is it manual or automatic? regarding the point you mentioned, I also think that the method shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier should have been called before PrepareSegue..but till now I am trying to find out why that is happening and how to solve it

Comment: Segues can *only* be created from the StoryBoard - you cannot create them any other way. When I say "automatic" I mean the segue is triggered automatically by a connection in StoryBoard, and "manual" is when you explicitly call `performSegueWithIdentifier` in your code. If you select a button, for example, in StoryBoard, and then check the `Connections Inspector` pane, you should see a `Triggered Segues` section at the top, and an `action` if a segue is connected to that button.

Comment: Note that I've seen people have a Segue connected to a button *and* have an IBAction connected to that button, in which they *also* call `performSegueWithIdentifier` - which, as you might guess, can cause all sorts of issues.

Comment: Ah - I bet that's *exactly* what you've done...

Comment: @DonMag so would you please suggest a solution?

Comment: @user2121 If I understand correctly your intentions, couldn't it do the condition check directly from within the `IBAction` method and decide here if it must call `performSegueWithIdentifier` instead of post checking in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` when the segue is about to be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have your Segue **connected** to a button, but you *also* have an IBAction connected to that button... and in your IBAction code you are manually calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` for that same Segue.

To create a Segue that you want to call manually, instead of ctrl-dragging from the button, ctrl-drag from the Controller icon:

[image]

Now, instead of using `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` to determine whether or not to proceed, you can put that logic inside your IBAction method.